# PHP Simple HTML DOM - Table row by row

Tags: php, html, dom

I currently can parse a html table using simplehtmldom. The problem I have is that the program prints the entire table in one block.

How would I print row by row?

How could I limit the rows to just the ones with times? (see http://www.masjid-umar.org/downloads/timetable_apr.htm)

Below is the code I am currently using:

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$dom = file_get_html('http://www.masjid-umar.org/downloads/timetable_apr.htm');
$table = $dom->find('table',0);
$rows = $table->children(0)->children();
foreach($rows as $row)
    foreach($row->children() as $column) {{
        if(!empty($column->innertext)) {
            echo $column->innertext . '<br />' . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}
```

The following is printed http://pastebin.com/cAMECf9f

Answer (score 0):

You could store the individual cells in a multi-dimensional array and loop through that to output it, but if you just want the table, you can skip the loops and do something like:

```
$table = $dom->find('table',0);
echo $table->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just search for the times:

```
foreach($dom->find('tr') as $tr){
  if(!preg_match('/\d+\.\d+/', $tr->text())) continue;
  echo $tr->text() . "\n";
}
```